# recharts tooltip cursor - dashed line

Tags: reactjs, recharts

I'm currently developing a chart, and one of the asks is that the "hover line" for the tooltip (the one that gets turned on/off with the cursor property on Tooltip should be dashed, not solid. On many of the recharts components, there is a "strokeDasharray" property that allows you to set it to something like '3 3' in order to get them to display as dashed lines (CartesianGrid, eg, among others). I am wondering how to do this for the vertical line that is displayed for the "active line" on a Tooltip.
[active tooltip vertical line](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T2YH8.png)
Unfortunately, searching for Tooltip and cursor doesn't bring up any useful information. I'm hoping that there is something simple, like the "strokeDasharray" property that I can set true, and I just can't find it?

I've searched documentation, I've tried setting the cursor to something other than true/false (I tried '3 3' eg but doesn't work). I can turn the line on or off but cannot determine how to alter its appearnace.

Edit: Here is the code. I didn't include it originally because I thought it would be fairly standard for a tooltip:

```
<Tooltip content={CustomTooltip} cursor={true}/>
```

I am looking for how to specify the cursor as a dashed line. Setting it to true turns it on, setting it to false turns it off, but I cannot find a way to modify its appearance.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

```
<Tooltip
  cursor={{
    stroke: "#BABABA",
    strokeWidth: 2,
    strokeDasharray: "5 5",
  }}
/>
```